# What does wait() do on Unix?

Tags: c, unix, ubuntu, wait

I was reading about the `wait()` function in a Unix systems book. The book contains a program which has `wait(NULL)` in it. I don't understand what that means. In other program there was

```
while(wait(NULL)>0)
```

...which also made me scratch my head.

Can anybody explain what the function above is doing?

Comment: `man 2 wait` can answer your question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

man [wait(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait)

> All  of  these  system  calls  are  used to wait for state changes in
>   a child of the calling process, and obtain information about the child
>   whose state has changed. A state change is considered to be: the child terminated; the child was stopped by a signal; or the child was resumed by a signal

So `wait()` allows a process to wait until one of its child processes change its state, exists for example. If `waitpid()` is called with a process id it waits for that *specific* child process to change its state, if a `pid` is not specified, then it's equivalent to calling `wait()` and it waits for *any* child process to change its state.

The `wait()` function returns child pid on success, so when it's is called in a loop like this:

```
while(wait(NULL)>0)
```

It means wait until all child processes exit (or change state) and no more child processes are unwaited-for (or until an error occurs)

Comment: There is some confusion between `wait` and `waitpid` in the answer. It is not possible to call `wait` with a process id.

Comment: Sorry, but there is an error left in your answer, wait doesn't return 0 on success, otherwise your while loop would exit at the first iteration. From the man page: "wait(): on success, returns the process ID of the terminated child;" (and exist means something different than exit)

Answer (score 2):

a quick google suggests, `wait(NULL)` waits for any of the child processes to complete

Answer (score 0):

`wait(NULL)` which should be equivalent to `waitpid(-1, NULL, 0)`

`wait(NULL)` waits for all the child processes to complete

Comment: that is wait(NULL) waits for any child process created by the process calling wait()

Comment: @UmerFarooq: Updated my answer as well!!

Comment: @LearnedfromMistake Wait for all the child and wait for any child doesn't mean the same thing. all=every, any="the first one which changes state"