# What's this fork-based pattern?

Tags: c, unix, fork, posix, waitpid

while searching for accept4(2) page, i came across the interesting code below. can anyone help me understand this fork-pattern please? (:

```
        /* Make the process the grandchild so we don't have to worry about waiting for it later.  */

        if  (pid != 0)  {
#ifdef  HAVE_WAITPID
                while  (waitpid(pid, (int *) 0, 0) < 0  &&  errno == EINTR)
                        ;
#else
                PIDTYPE wpid;
                while  ((wpid = wait((int *) 0)) != pid  &&  (wpid >= 0 || errno == EINTR))
                        ;
#endif
```

. not looking for difference in wait(2) vs waitpid(2) but specifically    'grandson' comment in the code.

.. did refer this [What does wait() do on Unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216554/what-does-wait-do-on-unix)    but not useful.

thanks,
~viren

Comment: There's not really enough context (code) to be able to say anything for certain.

Comment: The "grandchild" pattern (double-fork()) is used if the parent doesn't want to care about the child anymore. The main process forks the child. The child forks the grandchild and exits. The parent waits for the child. The grandchild is now a child of (usually) the init process (1), which will reap it automatically on exit.

Comment: Usually it's more likely that it's the parents, not the grand-parents, who call their children demons, but the general idea is right.

Comment: Double fork() is typically used to make spawned process be owned by init. See manual page daemon(7).

Comment: Ctx can you please put your comment as answer please? I will accept it because that’s what I was precisely looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the code before is made to launch a process in a way that its life is entirely detached from that running code. So a child of a child is ran to exec the interesting code, but the intermediate process (the direct child) need to be removed from the process list, so the waiting code to remove the zombie.
The full pattern is probably that one:

```
if (fork()==0) { // child
    if (fork()==0) { /// gran child
        // interesting things happens here in "detached" mode
        exec(..;);
        exit(...);
    }
    // direct child is of no use,
    // just to build the detached granchild,
    // disappear immediatly
    exit(...);
}
wait(...); // need to remove the child zombie (wait or waitpid)
```